# What can we do in self-isolation?

Tags: discussion

Now the whole nation is recommended to act like musicians usually do. Isn't this touching!

I think most of us don't have to change a lot ;)

Comment: What about musicians who do more of the Touring-side of Music though :)

Answer (score 6):

What could we do ... than just *act naturally*?

*Here's my second 'Self-Isolation Sesson' from home. It's an impromptu solo improvisation of 'All The Things You Are' I'm going to post a new video like this every Friday during this self-isolation period. Please stay well and stay safe. Love & Peace, Martin x*

Comment: +1 for a bit of sunshine in another potentially depressing day! What's the matter, people?

Comment: Nice. And some nice guitars!